# How to have an additional coloumn in a heatmaply heatmap

Tags: r, heatmaply

I am using heatmaply to obtain clustered heatmaps of responses from multiple raters on a series of questions rated using the same Leikert scale (ECOG Performance Status). The heatmap comes out well (though using hierarchical clustering on ordinal data like this may not be best). I would like to display an additional coloumn in the heatmap that has color coded information on an additional variable e.g. Age. 
The example heatmap I have generated using the package is attached. The coloumn in blue has information on patient's gender but the same is not color coded. I would like to know if the same can be done. Also would welcome any inputs as to the correct clustering methodology to be used for ordinal data.
[Original heatmap link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTY2h.png)
[image: heatmap]

The code used is here:

```
library(heatmaply)
data4 <- structure(list(UID = c("D1", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", 
"D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16"), R101 = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), R102 = c(3, 2, 0, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2), R103 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3), R104 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2), R105 = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 
3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2), R106 = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 4, 4), R107 = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
3, 3), R108 = c(0, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    R109 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), R110 = c(1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), R111 = c(3, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2), R112 = c(1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("male", 
    "female"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("UID", "R101", 
"R102", "R103", "R104", "R105", "R106", "R107", "R108", "R109", 
"R110", "R111", "R112", "Gender"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

p <-heatmaply(data4[1:13],fontsize_row = 8,fontsize_col = 6,Rowv =F,grid_gap = 0.5,colors = viridis(n = 256, alpha = 1, begin = 1,end = 0, option = "viridis"),branches_lwd = 0.2,row_side_colors =as.factor( data4$Gender))
p
```

Comment: btw - for discrete heatmaps, you can fake a discrete colour scale. See the code [here](https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/blob/master/R/plots.R#L636). Sorry for the lack of comments in the code, I could write a gist to explain the process in future.

Comment: Thanks. I data frame tip did the trick for me I removed the UID coloumn and the gender color is now discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does produce a colour-coded annotation for both factors. However, when there are enough levels, the colour scheme defaults to a rainbow scheme, which can be difficult to distinguish. You may need to try to subset the heatmap, or to try setting a different `row_side_palette` in `heatmaply`.

You might also want to pass the `row_side_colors` as a `data.frame` rather than a vector to ensure they are named correctly in both rownames and hovertext.

See the code below, which includes a few minor tweaks.

```
heatmaply(
  data4[, setdiff(colnames(data4), c("Gender", "UID"))],
  plot_method = "plotly",
  fontsize_row = 8,
  fontsize_col = 6,
  Rowv = FALSE,
  grid_gap = 0.5,
  colors = viridis(n = 256, alpha = 1, begin = 1,end = 0, option = "viridis"),
  branches_lwd = 0.2,
  row_side_colors = data4[, c("Gender", "UID")])
```

[image]